# Asp.net mvc user management

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

In asp.net mvc default application you get he account controller which enable user registration, log in, log out and changing password.

I was wondering is it possible to implement litle more like enabling administrator to delete some user or give some user different roles like in asp.net configuration where you create user, roles and asign roles to users?

I already figured out and extend profile for users, so now they have much more infos and profile picture.

If you have any experience or examples of user management in asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 3):

Although a bit outdated, this project maybe can give you a few hints on how to implement membership administration in ASP.NET MVC:

[Asp.Net MVC Membership Starter Kit](https://github.com/TroyGoode/MembershipStarterKit)

Quote

> **What is the Asp.Net MVC Membership
>   Starter Kit?**
>
> The starter kit currently consists of
>   two things:
>
> 1. A sample website containing the controllers, models, and views needed
>      to administer users & roles.
> 2. A library that provides testable interfaces for administering users &
>      roles and concrete implementations of
>      those interfaces that wrap the
>      built-in Asp.Net Membership & Roles
>      providers.
>
> Out of the box, the starter kit gives
>   you the following features:
>
> - List of Users
> - List of Roles
> - User Account Info
> - Change Email Address
> - Change a User's Roles

**Update**

For restricting certain operations to specific user roles, you can create these roles using the project I mentioned earlier, and then decorate your own application's controllers and/or actions with an Authorize attribute, referencing the desired roles:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, HR")]
public ActionResult DeleteUser(int UserId)
{
    // do something
}
```

This would prevent users that are not Administrator or HR to delete users.

Comment: Thanks for this i would appriciate just example of action where you find out user id or something to delete it or edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my try for a reusable user & role management:
https://github.com/Epstone/Simple-MVC-User-Management

Comment: How do you add it to a project? Instructions in github are not clear

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd create a Admin "module" which handles all of these things. I don't know of any asp.net documentation on this, but if you look around on PHP documentation (Zend Framework, CakePHP or other) you get the basic ideas of the structures you should use to achieve this. Just remember to keep things seperated, admin stuff goes into a admin module not a user module (but maybe a user controller inside a admin module).

Comment: My idea is to separate this controller and only my admin can acces it, so i have separate admin section with lot's of user information i would just like to add 2 more things, deleting user and changing his role, I hope using roles in win forms authetntication is somthing you understand.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question here:
[User Management in ASP.Net MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565444/user-management-in-asp-net-mvc-3/10522484#10522484)

This provides you with an MVC 3 Razor based User Management Tool. This does *not* include Roles, but if you get this far, it should not be real difficult to add them.